# Print loadings and yloadings details in R

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R and have been asked to prepare a script that will be used to capture some R output in a text file.

I have been given a set of commands that creates DB connection, loads data and then performs some mathematical calculation and churns out Summary, Loadings and YLoadings. I am to capture this output and save it in database. I have got everything working already except one bit that keeps on giving issues time and again.

The loadings and yloadings functions sometime gives out Matrix that has white-spaces in it. For example,

```
       Comp 1, Comp 2, Comp 3
Row1   0.495  0.748 -0.272
Row2   0.605        -0.562
Row3   0.666 -0.397  0.781
Row4                     
LongNameRow1   0.536        -1.483
LongNameRow2  -0.681 -0.408 -1.145
```

Because of such outputs I have to manually check the files and edit them so that they become,

```
      Comp 1, Comp 2, Comp 3
Row1  0.495  0.748 -0.272
Row2  0.605  0.000 -0.562
Row3  0.666 -0.397  0.781
Row4  0.000  0.000  0.000
LongNameRow1  0.536  0.000 -1.483
LongNameRow2 -0.681 -0.408 -1.145
```

i.e. I have to manually replace all the spaces with 0.000 (I am not sure of 0.000 is the correct value, but this was the only thing I could think of) in the output. This is very time consuming and painful to do.

I did some search around the loadings function and found,

> > Small loadings are conventionally not printed (replaced by spaces), to draw the eye to the pattern of the larger loadings.

So my question is, Are there any other methods or any configuration that I am missing that can give me the Output the way I need? i.e. 0.000 instead of white spaces or any other reasonable value? At the very least I am wondering if I can delimit the output with commas or the pipe character (i.e. "|") or something similar to make parsing the text possible?

Thanks in advance for help!!!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use `unclass` to convert the loadings to a matrix.  The following example illustrates this.

The `loadings` function extracts the loadings matrix and changes the class of this matrix to `loadings`.  When you print an object of class `loadings`, small values are not printed, as you observe.

Here is the example from `?princomp`:

```
fit <- princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)
l <- loadings(fit)
l

Loadings:
         Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
Murder   -0.536  0.418 -0.341  0.649
Assault  -0.583  0.188 -0.268 -0.743
UrbanPop -0.278 -0.873 -0.378  0.134
Rape     -0.543 -0.167  0.818       

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00
```

It is quite straightforward to change the class of this object back to its default.  If you then print it, the values are displayed as the true underlying values

```
l <- unclass(l)
l

             Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3      Comp.4
Murder   -0.5358995  0.4181809 -0.3412327  0.64922780
Assault  -0.5831836  0.1879856 -0.2681484 -0.74340748
UrbanPop -0.2781909 -0.8728062 -0.3780158  0.13387773
Rape     -0.5434321 -0.1673186  0.8177779  0.08902432
```